# Database and the 2nd Normal Form

Tags: database, database-normalization

I have a table that satisfies the following relations:

```
R(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N)
{A, B, C} is the primary key. 
{D, E} forms a candidate key. 

The following functional dependencies exist among the attributes of the relation:
{A, B} -> {H,I}
{D} -> {F,G}
{J} -> {K,L}
{E} -> {M,N}
```

I need to decompose this to the 2nd normal form, so I separate `{AB->HI}, {D->FG}, {E->MN}` into independent tables. But how about `{J->KL}`? How should I normalize this one?

Comment: J->KL I believe is a transitive dependancy, which I think is allowed in 2nd normal form, but not 3rd.

Comment: Does J->KL satisfy a transitive dependency because of ABC->DEJKL or DE->ABCJKL?

Comment: It's transitive because KL depends on the Primary Key THROUGH J.  Also, it's been a while since I've taken a DB course, so if I'm incorrect, please anyone feel free to correct me.  I'm about 90% sure that's right though.

Comment: I'm sure you're right about 3NF, but I'm not sure if I need to put one or **both** of the relations down in my comment above.

Comment: If I understand your question right, the first one is correct.
ABC->DEJKL

Comment: Were you given "{A, B, C} is the primary key" and "{D, E} forms a candidate key", or did you deduce those from the functional dependencies?

Comment: These are not deduced, these are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table is in 2nf if and only if all nonprime attributes are functionally dependent on all the attributes of every candidate key, not just on a subset of attributes of any candidate key.

According to your comment, you're given two keys, {ABC} and {DE}.

In the case of {AB}->{HI}, the attributes H and I are dependent on part of a key. ({AB} is part of the key {ABC}.) So you're correct in projecting {HI} from R. Ditto for {D}->{FG} and {E}->{MN}.

- R<sub>1</sub> = {ABCDEJKL}
- R<sub>2</sub> = {ABHI}
- R<sub>3</sub> = {DFG}
- R<sub>4</sub> = {EMN}

When it comes to the attributes J, K, and L, you have to ask the same question.

- Is J functionally dependent on any combination of the attributes A, B, C, D, and E, excluding the given keys {ABC} and {DE}?
- Is K functionally dependent on any combination of the attributes A, B, C, D, and E, excluding the given keys {ABC} and {DE}?
- Is L functionally dependent on any combination of the attributes A, B, C, D, and E, excluding the given keys {ABC} and {DE}?

What do you think about J, K, and L?

Comment: Doesn't answer the three bullet questions. Do you know how to determine whether, say, K is functionally dependent on any combination of the attributes A, B, C, D, and E?

Comment: I think I do. AB->J, BC->J, or AC->J is considered **partially** dependent; while ABC->J->KL, or DE->J->KL is considered **transitively** dependent. So in this case, K would be transitively dependent on both ABC and DE.

Comment: Right, assuming you already know that in this specific case, AB doesn't determine J, and that you were just using that as an example. You're right about the transitive dependencies. Since your goal is go reach at least 2NF, you don't need to do anything about transitive dependencies. (That's for 3NF.)

Answer (score 0):

According to your FD's :

I think your selection of PK/CK is not good here.

Only CK / PK would be ={ABCDEJ} Because closure of {ABCDEJ} ={ABCDEFGHILKLMN}All Attributes , Hence Prime attributes (6)={A,B,C,D,E,J}

In 2NF , we don't allow partial dependencies.
Here Partial Functional Dependencies:
{A, B} -> {H,I} {D} -> {F,G}  {J} -> {K,L} {E} -> {M,N}

So after removing these Partial Dependencies your table will be decomposed like this([Removal of Partial Dependency in 2NF](http://ashishparihargatenotes.blogspot.in/2016/03/database-management-system-best-one.html)):

R1 = {ABHI}

R2 = {DFG}

R3 = {JKL}

R4 = {EMN}

R5 = {ABCDEJ}